# Create a webview link on Bubblebottombar flutter

Tags: flutter

I would appreciate your help, I am trying to create a link in the menu of my app, the link would be to open my YouTube channel through webview, can someone tell me how it is possible? Thanks a lot

[dasboardactivity.dart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KD1c4.png)

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Center(
      child: getView(currentPage),
    ),
  ),
  bottomNavigationBar: BubbleBottomBar(
    opacity: .2,
    currentIndex: currentPage,
    backgroundColor: appStore.appBarColor,
    elevation: 8,
    onTap: changePage,
    hasNotch: false,
    hasInk: true,
    inkColor: appStore.appColorPrimaryLightColor,
    items: <BubbleBottomBarItem>[
      tab("home-run.png", keyString(context, "title_bookStore")),
      tab(
          "librarysolid.png",
          isLoginIn
              ? keyString(context, "title_myLibrary")
              : keyString(context, "lbl_categories")),
      tab("search.png", keyString(context, "title_search")),
      tab("user.png", keyString(context, "title_account")),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve with [flutter webview package](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          WebView(
            initialUrl: this.url,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onPageFinished: (finish) {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
            },
          ),
          isLoading
              ? Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : Stack(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

You can use an Stack in order to place it wherever you need it